# Coordinator Layout leaves padding on the bottom in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-fullscreen

Like a lot of other users, I'm having issues removing the bottom padding of the coordinator layout. I'm not sure if it's because the coordinator layout is implemented in the library by translation without resizing, or if I'm missing a flag.

On load:

[image: On load]

On scroll:

[image: On scroll]

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.pitchedapps.frost.views.FrostViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/kau_fab_margin"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried adding and removing `fitsSystemWindows` to the coordinator layout and appbar layout, but neither have helped.

The goal of this layout is to hide the status bar and nav bar, and to allow both the toolbar and tablayout to scroll out (which is why they are in a linear layout).

I have the following flags set in my main activity:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus && Prefs.mainActivityLayout == MainActivityLayout.FULL_SCREEN) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
    }
}
```

The full source of this layout can be found under `activity_main_hidden_tabs.xml` from [here](https://github.com/AllanWang/Frost-for-Facebook/tree/feature/fullscreen-mode/app/src/main/res/layout). There are other variants for reference, but they do not have to be full screen.

Comment: try this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout I fixed this issue by not using coordinator layout instead i placed a card view inside a RecyclerView the card view has two text view inside it When I move to larger screen size text size dictates the view and prevents cut off

Comment: Which part of that exactly helps with this? Recyclerviews likely won't cut it because I want the toolbar appearing whenever the user scrolls down. The only way I see it through is if I manually set boundaries, which defeats the purpose of the support library. That also negatively impacts things like the fab which depends on the coordinator layout for proper animations